# Watchpack Error (initial scan): Error: ENOTDIR: not a directory, scandir 'F:\some_dir\sneat\resources\assets\vendor\libs\highlight\highlight.js'

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, npm

I've installed [Sneat Laravel Admin Panel](https://github.com/themeselection/sneat-bootstrap-html-laravel-admin-template-free). I changed the sass, sass-loader, and auto-prefixer versions from what they provided to get rid of a few warnings. Now, when I put '*npm run dev*', Laravel Mix builds successfully. But when I give command '*npm run watch*', it says laravel mix build is successful but also shows this error in terminal: "***Watchpack Error (initial scan): Error: ENOTDIR: not a directory, scandir 'F:\some_dir\sneat\resources\assets\vendor\libs\highlight\highlight.js'***". I'm able to see the dashboard without any problems and couldn't identify any problems in local. **Can anyone help me understand how to solve this problem? Can I ignore this problem? May it be a problem if I deploy the app to production?**

My webpack.mix.json:

```
    const { EnvironmentPlugin } = require('webpack');
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
const glob = require('glob');
const path = require('path');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Configure mix
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */

mix.options({
  resourceRoot: process.env.ASSET_URL || undefined,
  processCssUrls: false,
  postCss: [require('autoprefixer')]
});

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Configure Webpack
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */

mix.webpackConfig({
  output: {
    publicPath: process.env.ASSET_URL || undefined,
    libraryTarget: 'window'
  },
  stats: {
    children: true,
  },
  plugins: [
    new EnvironmentPlugin({
      // Application's public url
      BASE_URL: process.env.ASSET_URL ? `${process.env.ASSET_URL}/` : '/'
    })
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.es6$|\.js$/,
        include: [
          path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules/bootstrap/'),
          path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules/popper.js/'),
          path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules/shepherd.js/')
        ],
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          presets: [['@babel/preset-env', { targets: 'last 2 versions, ie >= 10' }]],
          plugins: [
            '@babel/plugin-transform-destructuring',
            '@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread',
            '@babel/plugin-transform-template-literals'
          ],
          babelrc: false
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  externals: {
    jquery: 'jQuery',
    moment: 'moment',
    'datatables.net': '$.fn.dataTable',
    jsdom: 'jsdom',
    velocity: 'Velocity',
    hammer: 'Hammer',
    pace: '"pace-progress"',
    chartist: 'Chartist',
    'popper.js': 'Popper',

    // blueimp-gallery plugin
    './blueimp-helper': 'jQuery',
    './blueimp-gallery': 'blueimpGallery',
    './blueimp-gallery-video': 'blueimpGallery'
  }
});

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Vendor assets
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */

function mixAssetsDir(query, cb) {
  (glob.sync('resources/assets/' + query) || []).forEach(f => {
    f = f.replace(/[\\\/]+/g, '/');
    cb(f, f.replace('resources/assets/', 'public/assets/'));
  });
}

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Configure sass
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */

const sassOptions = {
  precision: 5
};

// Core stylesheets
mixAssetsDir('vendor/scss/**/!(_)*.scss', (src, dest) =>
  mix.sass(src, dest.replace(/(\\|\/)scss(\\|\/)/, '$1css$2').replace(/\.scss$/, '.css'), { sassOptions })
);

// Core javascripts
mixAssetsDir('vendor/js/**/*.js', (src, dest) => mix.js(src, dest));

// Libs
mixAssetsDir('vendor/libs/**/*.js', (src, dest) => mix.js(src, dest));
mixAssetsDir('vendor/libs/**/!(_)*.scss', (src, dest) =>
  mix.sass(src, dest.replace(/\.scss$/, '.css'), { sassOptions })
);
mixAssetsDir('vendor/libs/**/*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif}', (src, dest) => mix.copy(src, dest));
// Copy task for form validation plugin as premium plugin don't have npm package
mixAssetsDir('vendor/libs/formvalidation/dist', (src, dest) => mix.copyDirectory(src, dest));

// Fonts
mixAssetsDir('vendor/fonts/*/*', (src, dest) => mix.copy(src, dest));
mixAssetsDir('vendor/fonts/!(_)*.scss', (src, dest) =>
  mix.sass(src, dest.replace(/(\\|\/)scss(\\|\/)/, '$1css$2').replace(/\.scss$/, '.css'), { sassOptions })
);

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Application assets
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */

mixAssetsDir('js/**/*.js', (src, dest) => mix.scripts(src, dest));
mixAssetsDir('css/**/*.css', (src, dest) => mix.copy(src, dest));

mix.copy('node_modules/boxicons/fonts/*', 'public/assets/vendor/fonts/boxicons');

mix.version();

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Browsersync Reloading
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | BrowserSync can automatically monitor your files for changes, and inject your changes into the browser without requiring a manual refresh.
 | You may enable support for this by calling the mix.browserSync() method:
 | Make Sure to run `php artisan serve` and `yarn watch` command to run Browser Sync functionality
 | Refer official documentation for more information: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/mix#browsersync-reloading
 */

mix.browserSync('http://127.0.0.1:8000/');
```

resources\assets\vendor\libs\highlight\highlight.js->

```
import hljs from 'highlight.js/lib/index';

export { hljs };
```

and package.json

```
{
  "name": "sneat-bootstrap-html-laravel-admin-template-free",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "mix",
    "watch": "mix watch",
    "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
    "hot": "mix watch --hot",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "mix --production"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.9.2",
    "apexcharts-clevision": "^3.28.3",
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.5",
    "bootstrap": "~5.1.3",
    "boxicons": "~2.0.9",
    "highlight.js": "~9.17.1",
    "jquery": "~3.5.1",
    "masonry-layout": "~4.2.1",
    "perfect-scrollbar": "~1.5.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.25",
    "browser-sync": "^2.27.7",
    "browser-sync-webpack-plugin": "2.3.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "laravel-mix": "^6.0.6",
    "lodash": "^4.17.19",
    "postcss": "^8.1.14",
    "resolve-url-loader": "5.0.0",
    "sass": "1.55.0",
    "sass-loader": "13.2.0"
  }
}
```